# Munin haproxy plugin is not getting data even though munin-run show data and other plugins work fine

Tags: haproxy, munin

I have a Munin server (2.72) monitoring a lot of servers fine.

I have a haproxy server with munin-node (2.0.73) running fine for every plugin except haproxy_* (haproxy_sessions_frontend, haproxy_bytes_frontend, haproxy_rate_frontend, etc.) which give me NaN values.

When I test the plugin locally on the haproxy server I get relevant values :

```
# Skipping systemd properties simulation due to required systemd version (999)
# Processing plugin configuration from /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/00-default
# Processing plugin configuration from /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/haproxy
# Processing plugin configuration from /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node
# Setting /rgid/ruid/ to /982/0/
# Setting /egid/euid/ to /982 982/0/
# Setting up environment
# Environment frontend = https_front haproxy-monitoring fe-letsencrypt
# Environment url = http://127.0.0.1:8080/haproxy_stats;csv;norefresh
# Environment backend = app-main haproxy-monitoring letsencrypt-backend
# About to run '/etc/munin/plugins/haproxy_sessions_frontend'
scurea490f35148af7011c03b86177948440.value 3
smaxea490f35148af7011c03b86177948440.value 25
scur4dc7a8e588e9bb787fe6e39c1c96957a.value 1
smax4dc7a8e588e9bb787fe6e39c1c96957a.value 2
scura92191189150289a82c2c4464351178c.value 0
smaxa92191189150289a82c2c4464351178c.value 5
```

When I connect remotely from the Munin server, this is what I get :

```
bash-4.4$ /usr/share/munin/munin-update --debug --nofork --host servxxx.domain.tld --service haproxy_session_frontend
2023/10/05 17:12:57 [DEBUG] Creating new lock file /var/run/munin/munin-update.lock
2023/10/05 17:12:57 [DEBUG] Creating lock : /var/run/munin/munin-update.lock succeeded
2023/10/05 17:12:57 [INFO]: Starting munin-update
2023/10/05 17:12:58 [DEBUG] Creating new lock file /var/run/munin/munin-datafile.lock
2023/10/05 17:12:58 [DEBUG] Creating lock : /var/run/munin/munin-datafile.lock succeeded
2023/10/05 17:12:58 [DEBUG] Writing state to /var/lib/munin/datafile.storable
2023/10/05 17:12:58 [DEBUG] about to write '/var/lib/munin/datafile.storable'
2023/10/05 17:12:58 [INFO]: Munin-update finished (1.47 sec)
```

But my rrd files are filled with NaN and in the munin-update.log I get this warning every time Munin tries to update data from the node :

```
2023/10/05 17:15:13 [WARNING] 6 lines had errors while 0 lines were correct (100.00%) in data from 'fetch haproxy_sessions_frontend' on haproxy.captcha/x.x.x.x:4949
```

I've tried nearly everything from this page https://guide.munin-monitoring.org/en/latest/tutorial/troubleshooting.html but I'm clueless.
The same plugin is working well on another haproxy server. The main difference is the other server is running Rocky Linux 8 and the one with issue is running Rocky Linux 9

What can I do to get this plugin running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit in /var/log/messages

Some calls were denied by SELinux. After adding the suggested rule below, everything works as expected.

**Log extract :**

server setroubleshoot[681531]: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/curl from name_connect access on the tcp_socket port 8080.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that curl should be allowed name_connect access on the port 8080 tcp_socket by default. Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do allow this access for now by executing:

```
ausearch -c 'curl' --raw | audit2allow -M my-curl
semodule -X 300 -i my-curl.pp
```

Comment: PS: there is a note about SELinux potential issue in the Munin doc but the provided link is dead